# Is there any way to disable "resource saver mode" in Docker desktop?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

With Docker [4.22](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-desktop-4-22/) came a new "Resource Saver Mode". However, this is considerably slowing me down as it now takes **several minutes** to do any operations, such as running a container, when Docker is running in saver mode.

**So, is there a way to disable Resource Saver Mode? Or is the only option to downgrade Docker desktop?**

*Note: I am running Docker desktop version 4.22.1 on macOS.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Docker Desktop *for Windows*, you can go to **Settings** / **Features in development** / **Experimental features**, and uncheck **Access experimental features**, then **Apply & restart**.

My guess is that on Mac you have the same setting.

Comment: On Mac I had to restart Docker Desktop completely after disabling the flag (Quit and then start Docker.app again) as Apply & restart didn't the trick.

Comment: Now it has moved to `Resources > Enable resource saver`